# SQL Server Alternating Group Of Rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═══╗
║       DATETIME          ║ M ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═══╣
║ 2015-06-17 15:03:44.840 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 15:03:33.940 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 15:03:32.950 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 15:03:22.060 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 15:03:11.210 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 14:50:12.950 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 13:50:12.850 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:50:12.790 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:49:10.410 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:59.510 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:48.630 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:37.730 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:26.830 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:15.940 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:14.950 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:48:04.060 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:47:53.170 ║ 1 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:47:42.280 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:44:14.350 ║ 0 ║
║ 2015-06-17 12:43:08.970 ║ 1 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═══╝
```

My objective is to select the group of zeros and ones and calculate the difference in date and time.

How can I achieve this?

My final result is to be able to find the consecutive occurrences of zeros and calculate the respective duration.

- # | T | Duration
- 1 | 0 | 2 hours and 13 minutes
- 2 | 0 | 3 minutes

Comment: What output exactly are you expecting? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to see as a result? Show the desired output..

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you post the desired result?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'm interested in the reoccurring group of zeros and their duration

Comment: You clarified nothing with your edit. Elaborate on 2 hours 13 minutes, how did you get that? We are not mindreaders. How did you get 3 minutes? Where is M = 1?

Comment: The duration is the sum of the difference in date time between each row. In my comment, I clarified that I'm only interested in the reoccurring group of zeros no need for M = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( d DATETIME, m INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '2015-06-17 15:03:44.840', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 15:03:33.940', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 15:03:32.950', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 15:03:22.060', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 15:03:11.210', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 14:50:12.950', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 13:50:12.850', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:50:12.790', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:49:10.410', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:59.510', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:48.630', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:37.730', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:26.830', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:15.940', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:14.950', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:48:04.060', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:47:53.170', 1 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:47:42.280', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:44:14.350', 0 ),
        ( '2015-06-17 12:43:08.970', 1 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY d DESC )
                        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY m ORDER BY d DESC ) rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(d) desc) AS [#],
            DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(d), MAX(d)) / 60 Hours,
            DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(d), MAX(d)) - ( DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(d), MAX(d)) / 60 ) * 60 Minutes
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   m = 0
    GROUP BY rn
```

Output:

```
#   Hours   Minutes
1   2       13
2   0       3
```

Inside CTE there is some gaps and island solution, then grouping by the rank and calculating the results.